# Migrating puppet from 3.x to 4x

Tags: puppet, erb, hiera

I have existing puppet modules written in hiera. Basically, data module with param.pp pattern. Everything works fine in puppet 3.x. But after setup with puppet 4.x and ran puppet agent, following error return for hash keys.

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Failed to parse template wso2ei/conf/carbon.xml.erb:
  Filepath: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/wso2ei/templates/conf/carbon.xml.erb
  Line: 138
  Detail: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/wso2base/manifests/push_templates.pp:23:16 at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/wso2base/manifests/configure.pp:59 on node puppet4-aa54a7f2-83a6-43d2-b8d7-c15a42591e88.openstacklocal
```

The particular section of carbon.xml.erb looks like below

```
<%- if @ports['offset'] -%>
        <Offset><%= @ports['offset'] %></Offset>
<%- else -%>
        <Offset>0</Offset>
<%- end -%>
```

hieradata set as below in yaml file

```
wso2::ports:
  offset: 0
```

param.pp written to read the data

```
   $ports                    = hiera('wso2::ports')
```

init.pp set value as below

```
  $ports                  = $wso2ei::params::ports,
```

Template not giving any error for a single line data. For an example in carbon.xml.erb

```
<% if @hostname %>
    <HostName><%= @hostname %></HostName>
<%- else -%>
    <!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->
<% end %>
```

hieradata in yaml file

```
wso2::hostname: "%{::fqdn}"
```

All hash keys getting the same error. When I Google, found that `@` has to replace with `scope` like below. But there are lots of places to change.

```
<%- if scope['wso2ei::params::ports']['offset'] -%>
        <Offset><%= scope['wso2ei::params::ports']['offset'] %></Offset>
<%- else -%>
        <Offset>0</Offset>
<%- end -%>
```

Is there a way to preserve existing param.pp data module pattern in puppet 4? Appreciate your help.

Comment: We need to see the manifest file (*.pp file) that calls the template. To answer your question briefly, params.pp certainly still works in Puppet 4.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for the response. Here is the public GitHub repo link of init.pp - https://github.com/wso2/puppet-ei/blob/master/manifests/init.pp. It calls the base puppet module and here it is https://github.com/wso2/puppet-base/tree/master/manifests

Comment: I am afraid I can't see any reason for that code to be failing in the way you describe. My guess is that for some reason, your Hiera data is not being found. I don't have enough information to reproduce the issue, and I think it would take too long to reproduce anyway, by the looks of it. I can tell you, though, that you shouldn't need to replace all the `@` with `scope[...]`. See the document here for more info: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.0/lang_template_erb.html#variable

Comment: Additionally, best practices for late Puppet 4.x is to migrate from the deprecated `params.pp` pattern to a Hiera module data design.